How to modify bits in the Page Table Entry (PTE) within the Linux kernel on ARM64?
I'm doing some research on ARMV8.9 new features called Permission Indirection, which is similar to X86 Memory Protection Key. The PIIndex (Permission Indirection Index, like MPK key) consists of PTE_UXN, PTE_PXN, PTE_WRITE, PTE_USER in PTE, and I try to modify these bits so to change the index. How I can do that?
In my kernel module, I allocate a page, and I use virt_to_kpte to get its PTE. And then I use ptep_get_and_clear and set_pte_at to reconfigure the PTE's PIIndex. This is my codes:
static __u64 set_kpage_piindex(unsigned long kaddr, __u64 piindex)
{
    pte_t *ptep, pte;
    __u64 old_piindex;

    ptep = virt_to_kpte(kaddr);
    pte = ptep_get_and_clear(&init_mm, kaddr, ptep);

    old_piindex = pte_pi_index((pte.pte));

    // clear piindex and reset
    pte = clear_pte_bit(pte, __pgprot(PTE_UXN | PTE_PXN | PTE_WRITE | PTE_USER));
    pte = set_pte_bit(pte, __pgprot((PTE_UXN & ((piindex) & 0x8) << 51) |
                                    (PTE_PXN & ((piindex) & 0x4) << 51) |
                                    (PTE_WRITE & ((piindex) & 0x2) << 50) |
                                    (PTE_USER & ((piindex) & 0x1) << 6)));

    set_pte_at(&init_mm, kaddr, ptep, pte);

    return old_piindex;
}

Besides I export init_mm to support the use of these kernel functions. But I notice a modify delay, which means, the actual modification may take effects some time after the setting. Theses two functions are the direct usage of ptep_modify_prot_start and ptep_modify_prot_commit:
static inline pte_t ptep_modify_prot_start(struct vm_area_struct *vma,
                       unsigned long addr,
                       pte_t *ptep)
{
    return __ptep_modify_prot_start(vma, addr, ptep);
}

static inline void ptep_modify_prot_commit(struct vm_area_struct *vma,
                       unsigned long addr,
                       pte_t *ptep, pte_t old_pte, pte_t pte)
{
    __ptep_modify_prot_commit(vma, addr, ptep, pte);
}

I did notice that the comments say "ptep_modify_prot_commit may not actually update the pte, but merely queue the update to be done at some later time.  The update must be actually committed before the pte lock is released, however". So how to avoid this modification delay? Kernel modification is acceptable.

I found a solution here. I need to flush the data cache after I set the PIIndex:
flush_dcache_page(virt_to_page(kaddr));

I'm not sure whether this is the right way to set PIIndex or not, but currently it works.
